# Why do my applets randomly crash?

Tags: indicator, applet

Ever since my upgrade to Natty Narwhal, applets (e.g, clock, weather indicator, indicator applet.) will crash the second I reach the desktop after logging into Ubuntu Classic. Which one is rather random, but it's *always* at least one or more of those. Is this a known bug, or is there something wrong with my system?

Comment: probably  a bug with indicator-applet

Comment: Would that affect all three of them though? I don't use the complete indicator-applet.

Comment: they are part of the package so i guess it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this bug has been reported before:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/537383

Your information seems to be useful since the bug was closed due to lack of information (given the number of people who reported themselves as affected I don't believe this should have happened).

You could try to reinstall the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-applet indicator-messages indicator-sound
```